# Dynamic array of Maps in C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, dynamic-memory-allocation

In a program which I'm coding I need to use an structure as this one:

```
static std::unordered_map<size_t, int> map[N][M];
```

The problem is that I need to generate the size of the map dynamically, so I would define:

```
static std::unordered_map<size_t, int> **map
```

But I'm having problems allocating it. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: As for your current problem with pointers, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

I recomment you use `std::vector` to manage your arrays. You can create a *vector of vectors* like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::unordered_map<size_t, int>>> map(M, std::vector<std::unordered_map<size_t, int>>(N));

for(int m = 0; m < M; ++m)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
        map[m][n].emplace(0, 1);
    }
}
```

If you know the sizes at compile time, you can use `std::array` which should be faster.

```
static std::array<std::array<std::unordered_map<size_t, int>, M>, N> map;
```

Comment: Just a minor addition to this answer - in case if you know the size of your arrays at compile time - I'd suggest to use std::array instead of vector. This way the compiler can make better optimizations to your code

Comment: In this case I know the size on runtime. Using the vector approach I found a solution. `static std::vector<std::vector<std::unordered_map<size_t, int>>> map;` `map.resize( num_of_col , std::vector<std::unordered_map<size_t, int>>( num_of_row ) );`

Comment: @Chaosit Added a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to allocate the space of `N * sizeof(std::unordered_map<size_t, int> *)`.